# AWS Streaming with Kinesis Firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I want to create a log delivery stream from the EC2 instance and stream it using firehose with source kinesis.

I install the kinesis agent on windows and it's running fine;

[image]

Here is my appsetting.json file inside AWSKinesisTap folder

```
{
"Sources": [
 {
  "Id": "SyslogDirectorySource",
  "SourceType": "DirectorySource",
  "Directory": "C:\\LogSource\\",
  "FileNameFilter": "*.log",
  "RecordParser": "SysLog",
  "TimeZoneKind": "UTC",
  "InitialPosition": "Bookmark"
 }
],
"Sinks": [
{
  "Id": "KinesisStreamSink",
  "SinkType": "KinesisStream",
  "StreamName": "SyslogKinesisDataStream",
  "Region": "us-east-1"
 }
 ],
 "Pipes": [
 {
  "Id": "SyslogDS2KSSink",
  "SourceRef": "SyslogDirectorySource",
  "SinkRef": "KinesisStreamSink"
  }
 ]
}
```

AWSKinisisTap log from ProgramData

```
 2021-03-06 13:15:06.0816 Amazon.KinesisTap.Hosting.LogManager INFO Config file changed.
 2021-03-06 13:15:09.4376 SyslogDirectorySource INFO DirectorySource id    SyslogDirectorySource watching directory C:\LogSource\ with filter *.log stopped.
2021-03-06 13:15:09.4376 Amazon.KinesisTap.Hosting.LogManager INFO Performance counter sink  stopped.
2021-03-06 13:15:09.7072 KinesisStreamSink INFO KinesisStreamSink id KinesisStreamSink for StreamName firehose stopped.
2021-03-06 13:15:09.7072 Amazon.KinesisTap.Hosting.LogManager INFO Log manager stopped.
2021-03-06 13:15:10.1990 Amazon.KinesisTap.Hosting.LogManager INFO Registered factory Amazon.KinesisTap.AWS.AWSEventSinkFactory.
 2021-03-06 13:15:10.1990 Amazon.KinesisTap.Hosting.LogManager INFO Registered factory Amazon.KinesisTap.Windows.PerformanceCounterSinkFactory.
 2021-03-06 13:15:11.1375 Amazon.KinesisTap.Hosting.LogManager INFO Registered factory Amazon.KinesisTap.Core.DirectorySourceFactory.
 2021-03-06 13:15:11.1375 Amazon.KinesisTap.Hosting.LogManager INFO Registered factory Amazon.KinesisTap.ExchangeSource.ExchangeSourceFactory.
 2021-03-06 13:15:11.1375 Amazon.KinesisTap.Hosting.LogManager INFO Registered factory Amazon.KinesisTap.Uls.UlsSourceFactory.
2021-03-06 13:15:11.1375 Amazon.KinesisTap.Hosting.LogManager INFO Registered factory Amazon.KinesisTap.Windows.WindowsSourceFactory.
2021-03-06 13:15:11.6037 Amazon.KinesisTap.Hosting.LogManager INFO Registered factory Amazon.KinesisTap.Core.Pipes.PipeFactory.
2021-03-06 13:15:12.0783 Amazon.KinesisTap.Hosting.LogManager INFO Registered factory Amazon.KinesisTap.AWS.CredentialProvider.ProfileRefreshingCredentialsFactory.
2021-03-06 13:15:12.5418 Amazon.KinesisTap.Hosting.LogManager INFO Registered factory Amazon.KinesisTap.AutoUpdate.AutoUpdateFactory.
2021-03-06 13:15:12.5418 Amazon.KinesisTap.Hosting.LogManager INFO Performance counter sink  started.
  2021-03-06 13:15:12.5522 KinesisStreamSink INFO KinesisStreamSink id KinesisStreamSink for StreamName SyslogKinesisDataStream started.
  2021-03-06 13:15:12.5522 Amazon.KinesisTap.Hosting.LogManager INFO Connected source SyslogDirectorySource to sink KinesisStreamSink
   2021-03-06 13:15:12.5522 SyslogDirectorySource INFO DirectorySource id SyslogDirectorySource watching directory C:\LogSource\ with filter *.log started.
```

Datastream from AWS

[image]

Firehose delivery stream

[image]

I have chosen kinesis stream from the data source and give full access in IAM roles. Data destination is an s3 bucket.

The problem is I am not getting any log files into AWS, no activity in the firehose, and no file in S3. What would be the problem?

Recent error

> 2021-03-07 19:16:36.5337 EventLogSink ERROR KinesisFirehoseSink EventLogSink client exception after 35 attempts: Amazon.KinesisFirehose.Model.InvalidArgumentException: This operation is not permitted on KinesisStreamAsSource delivery stream type. ---> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

The previous problem is gone after adding roles, now I have new problems

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: In the config it's called `"StreamName": "SyslogKinesisDataStream"` and in the Gui it seems to be called DataStream - seems weird

Comment: well, i am new to kinesis, i will change it and test. Thanks @Maurice

Comment: @Maurice, changed it, still noting after 5 min. my stream refresh time is 100 seconds

Comment: Can you manually publish sample data to your stream using aws cli [put-record](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/kinesis/put-record.html) to check if it goes through to s3?

Comment: @Marcin yes I check that and it was working

Comment: Can you post the full error log of the kinesis agent?

Comment: Can you also provide the policies attached to EC2?

Comment: You can stream logs directly to Kinesis firehose and don't need data stream

Comment: @AmanB, it has administrative access.